# How to use Promise in node v9.11?

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to use Promise in node.js, but it's not working properly. Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with my code? See the console they are the ordering outputs

```
let Dele = "Delete From VehicleImages WHERE Vehicle='"+VehicleId+"'"
db.query(Dele,function(err,del){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        for(let i=0; i<keyss.length; i++){
            let DocName = keyss[i];
            let FileData = files[DocName];
            let FileName = FileData.name;
            fs.mkdir('public/Vehicle/Img',{recursive:true},(err)=>{
                if (err){
                    FileData.mv('public/Vehicle/Img/'+FileData.name ,function(err) {
                        if (err){
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    FileData.mv('public/Vehicle/Img/'+FileData.name ,function(err) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err)
                        }
                    });
                } 
                pro = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                    let iid = uuid.v4();
                    let q = "INSERT INTO VehicleImages (Id,Vehicle,Document_FileName,Thumbnail_FileName) VALUES ('"+iid+"','"+VehicleId+"','"+FileName+"','"+FileName+"')";
                    console.log(q) third console
                    db.query(q,function(err,data){
                        if(err){
                            reject("error")
                        }else{
                            resolve('success')
                        }
                    })
                })
                obj.push(pro);
            })
        Promise.all(obj).then(function(value){
        console.log(obj ,"xxxxxxxxx") first console
            console.log(value) second console
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Add info what is desired output and what output do you get

Comment: please explain what do you mean by "properly". Describe both the expected and the actual behavior

Comment: You need to create a promise for every single of your asynchronous calls, not just one of them.